# painted form contents won't stay painted

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics

I've tried setting ResizeRedraw, but it was not causing paint events on resize, so I began invalidating inside myForm_Resize. Now when I resize, I see that my background is being repainted, but as soon as I stop resizing, my control is being repainted with its background color. What am I doing wrong?

```
private void pbox_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e) {
    Rectangle boardRect = pbox.ClientRectangle;
    using (Graphics g = pbox.CreateGraphics()) {
        g.FillRectangle(Brushes.Orange, boardRect);
    }
}

private void myForm_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    this.Invalidate(true);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that there is no point in creating `Graphics` object in `Paint` event handler. You should use existing `Graphics` object from the `PaintEventArgs`. Change your code like this, it should work now:

```
private void pbox_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e) 
{
      Rectangle boardRect = pbox.ClientRectangle;
      e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Orange, boardRect);
}
```

Comment: That works for keeping my contents painted. Any idea why ResizeRedraw doesn't trigger my Paint event?

Comment: It triggers, check in debugger, but using CreateGraphics is unstable and subsequent redraws of the control itself are canceling it. Try with any other control on the form like Button. CreateGraphics is used only when you need to draw something that will be visible until next redraw, in any other case, you should use the Graphics from the PaintEventArgs within Paint event handler or in the override of the OnPaint method.